Batch edit the URL links in ALL buttons in an InDesign document
So, I have a magazine that features a set of three buttons at the bottom of every page:
Email — Facebook — X
Each button delivers as intended, i.e., X button will share the page to X (with the article caption, etc.), email button  will automatically open the mail client of choice with everything set up to just add the @ and click send. Same for FB.
It repeats in every mag issue, but since the button link structure obiously changes with each issue number and page I have to manually update each and everyone and I do that with the Buttons pane one by one for every page. To add up, the pane –idk why– will like "cut" the URL in half (see pic) and that makes the task even more tedious.
The buttons link structure is the usual mailto: / sharer for FB / intent for X with the rest of the URL pointing to the page (magXX/pag Nº.html)
Is there any way to –even if manually– update all 144 buttons (48 pag x 3 buttons each page) at once?
I'm thinking in something that could deliver, idk, somtehing like an indexed log and from there, manually re writing as needed and then importing such log of some sort.
Thanks!

So, which picture ? Hyperlinks in a doc can be controlled via scripting, if you can do coding. Otherwise the UI does not come with any automation for replacing hyperlinks.

Yay. I was expecting that. Just my wishful thinking that InDesign somehow could've sorted this already.
I didn't know how to upload pic here, if that's even possible but imagine a line of text almost cut in half inside the tiny prompting area where links are put in the buttons pane.
